# Liquibase gradle: overriding changelogFile property for diffChangelog

Tags: liquibase

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to have the configuration in `liquibase.properties` to act as fallback values, and be able to override specific values for some of the gradle liquibase tasks:

Eg.
`diffChangelog` should not append the changesets to my master changelog file but instead output them to a new file, therefore i want to overwrite the changelogFile value to something different.

**liquibase.properties**

```
liquibase.hub.mode=off
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
changelogFile=src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.yml
referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.foo\
  ?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect\
  &hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy\
  &hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of your liquibase.properties file? 

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking, but you could try using property substitution - https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html 
If that doesn't work, and you'd like to request that this functionality be added, you can submit a request here: https://ideas.liquibase.com

Comment: @tabbyfoo I've added the current liquibase.properties file i have